# How to import Django Model to Tornado project?

Tags: python, django, tornado

I have an app written by Django. Then I want to develop a new app by Tornado which uses the Django's Model to provide data for client.

I have found this:[Using Django Inside the Tornado Web Server](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/2009/sep/15/using-django-inside-tornado-web-server/)

But in the blog, the author just give the code that we should define the Django Model again in Tornado project.

How do I do that we can import the defined Model in Tornado project avoiding repeating define.
help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do `from django.conf import settings` first. After that you can import your models and work with them like usually.

Comment: Could you give me some simple? Thanks!

Comment: In my current we do something like that https://gist.github.com/inlanger/728604b63a17331f90b8/

Comment: you need to be careful for this. because Tornado is non-blocking and Django is blocking.